# How do we prove that if $M$ is complete, any sequence $x_n \in M$ satisfying $d(x_n,x_{n+1}) < 2^{-n}$ converges in $M$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'd like to show that if $M$ is a metric space $(M,d)$, and is complete, any sequence $x_n \in M$ satisfying $d(x_n,x_{n+1}) < 2^{-n}$ converges in $M.

**My proof is the following:**

I think that this question is the same as showing that if all Cauchy sequences, say  $x_n \in M$ are convergent in $M$ (by definition of complete), then that sequence $x_n$ must also satisfy the condition $d(x_n,x_{n+1}) < 2^{-n}$. Is the proof as simple as choosing $\epsilon \leq 2^{-n}$ and then letting $m=n+1$? Since if we have that we can say:

Suppose $x_n \in M$ is a Cauchy sequence. Hence, it must be convergent. Then, by definition this means that given $\epsilon >0$, there exists an $N$ such that if $m,n \geq N$, $d(x_m,x_n)< \epsilon$.

Hence, just choose $\epsilon$ small enough so that $\epsilon \leq 2^{-n}$ and then let $m=n+1$. Then, pugging into the above, we will have the following statement:

given $0<\epsilon  \leq 2^{-n}$, there exists an $N$ such that if $m=n+1,n \geq N$, $d(x_m,x_n) = d(x_{n+1}, x_n) < \epsilon \leq 2^{-n}$. Hence, $x_n \in M$ satisfies

$d(x_{n+1}, x_n) < 2^{-n}$. And, since $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in a complete space, its also convergent.

I am wondering if the above makes sense. I am a bit wary of the part where I "choose" and "fix" the $\epsilon$. Thank you!

Comment: No. What you have is not a proof. It really makes not much sense, plus it is not proving anything like what is needed. What you need to verify is that any sequence that satisfies the assumption is Cauchy. This means that for any $\epsilon>0$ you need to find an $N$ such that if $n,m>N$, then $d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon$. You cannot start assuming already that the sequence is Cauchy, that is exactly what you need to prove. And it is not enough to say that if $n$ is small enough, then $d(x_n,x_{n+1}) <2^{-n}<\epsilon$. You really need to look at all $n,m>N$, not just at pairs $n,n+1$.

Comment: Did he show the backwards implication tho?

Answer (score 1):

The proof as stated is wrong. A simple counterexample is $(1,0,\frac{1}{3},0,\frac{1}{5},0,\ldots)$. Moreover, it tries to prove the wrong implication. What you need to prove is the following: if $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $M$ such that $d(x_n,x_{n+1})<2^{-n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. This suffices, since $M$ is complete.

A proof for this statement would look like this: for all $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $n\ge m$ it is true that $d(x_m,x_n)\le \sum_{k=m}^n d(x_k,x_{k+1})$. You can use induction to prove this. Choose $N$ such that $\sum_{k=m}^n 2^{-k}<\epsilon$ for all $n,m\ge N$. You can do this, since the geometric series converges (absolutely). It follows that $d(x_m,x_n)\le \sum_{k=m}^n d(x_k,x_{k+1})\le \sum_{k=m}^n 2^{-k}<\epsilon$ for all $m,n\ge N$, hence $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score -1):

Your proof is correct. For some large enough $N$, the distance between subsequent terms $x_n,x_{n+1}$ in any Cauchy sequence is less then $2^{-n}$, for any $n>N$.

**However, this is not what you have to prove. You need the other implication.**

Let $\{x_n\}^\infty$ be a sequence satisfying the property from your question. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Now choose a natural $N$ such that $\varepsilon>2^{-N}$. Such a number exists since the naturals are not bounded from above. Finally, consider any two natural numbers $n,m>N$. Do you see, by the triangle inequality, that $d(x_n,x_m)<2^{-N}<\varepsilon$? This makes the sequence a Cauchy sequence, and therefore it converges by completeness.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Question, did he correctly show the backward implication?

Comment: That is what I assert in my answer, @user123276. The last sentence of the proof is redundant. So are some other parts of the proof, yet the proof is sound. It is, however, a proof of the opposite implication of what user151719 wants to prove. Apparently, user151719’s thinking is somewhat confused.

Comment: No, the proof is not correct. It is not the case that if $(x_n)$ is Cauchy then $d(x_n,x_{n+1})<2^{-n}$. Surely, for any $n$ there is an $N$ such that if $m>N$, then $d(x_m,x_{m+1})<2^{-n}$, but this is different.

Comment: That is what I asserted. Did you read my answer?