# Being Cauchy in a metric space

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be metric space. Let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence satisfying the followig  in this space.

For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $x_{n+1}\in B_{d}(x_{n},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}})$ where $B_{d}(x_{n},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}})$ is the open ball $x_{n}$ centered with radius $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$. How can I show that this sequence is a Cauchy sequence? When I read the book, it says when the convergence of the geometric Serie $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}$, it is a Cauchy sequence but I could not get it. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: What can you say about $d(x_n, x_{n+1})$? What about $d(x_n, x_{n+2})$, $d(x_n, x_{n+3})$ ?..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we prove that if $M$ is complete, any sequence $x_n \in M$ satisfying $d(x_n,x_{n+1}) &lt; 2^{-n}$ converges in $M$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799932/how-do-we-prove-that-if-m-is-complete-any-sequence-x-n-in-m-satisfying-d)

Comment: For now nothing I guess, I am not able to consider it for now, I think I must focus, any hint can you say? @Ilya

Comment: Thank you very much @AnotherUser

Comment: there's already an answer based on this argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_{n+1}\in B(x_{n},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}})$ how far apart can $x_{m}$ and $x_{n}$ be for $m\geq n$ ?

$d(x_{n},x_{n+p})\leq d(x_{n},x_{n+1})+d(x_{n+1},x_{n+2})+...+d(x_{n+p-1},x_{n+p})$ due to the triangle inequality.

So $d(x_{n},x_{n+p})\leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}+...+\frac{1}{2^{n+p-1}}= \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{p}})\leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$

So as $n,p\to\infty$ , do you see that $d(x_{n},x_{n+p})\to 0$ ?

In general when $d(x_{n},x_{n+1})\leq \epsilon_{n}$ where $\sum_{n\geq 1}\epsilon_{n}<\infty$ ,

You can conclude that $(x_{n})$ is a Cauchy sequence because $d(x_{n},x_{m})$ would be bounded by a tail of a convergent series.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Can you please explain the $d(x_{n},x_{n+p})\to 0$ part ?

Comment: What do you want me to explain? $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$ . So given any $\epsilon$, you can find $N$ such that $n,p\geq N$ implies $d(x_{n},x_{n+p})<\epsilon\,\,,\forall n\geq N \,,p\geq 1$  . Or you can restate it like $d(x_{n},x_{m})<\epsilon\,,\forall n,m \, : N\leq n\leq m$ That is just the definition of a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will focus on this, I may be a little bit lack of this topic @Mr.GandalfSauron